# How to make landing page for separate html site that is linked to main?

Tags: css, background-image, image-gallery

how can I make landing page for separate site (in my case "gallery") which is opened in different bookmark.
Here how it looks:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgIKj.jpg)
I already made my main landing page and it works but when I try to rewrite it to this separate offer.html it does not work. This is my html "Gallery" code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    }
    
    div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    }
    
    div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
    
    div.desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
        <img src="img_5terre.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
        <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
        <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
        <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>

    <section class="landing-page-gallery">

    </section>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is what I have in my main page CSS code:

```
`.landing-page-gallery {
    width: 98,5vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    background-image: url(TRICK-landing.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}`
```

What should I do to make my gallery site looks exactly like my main page with background image and background color?

I have already tried to copy  CSS selector ".landing-page" into ".landing-page-gallery" but it changed nothing. As far as I imagine it should give the same result but no.

Comment: `width: 98,5vw;` is not valid. Use `.` for decimal values: `width: 98.5vw;`

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I just changed it. It hasn't solved my issue though

Comment: Okay then I think we need more details. You can make your code a runnable snippet with the `<>` button. In general couldn't you just use the same CSS for both pages? Then they would look the same. Then just use extra classes to override the differences.

Comment: I would like to use the same CSS but my current knowledge is not enough to execute this idea. That is why I continue my study and post this question hoping that someone will help in the meantime :)

Comment: What do you mean your knowledge isn't enough to use CSS on two pages? Just link a CSS file: [Documentation: the link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link). We can expect you to do tutorials and read documentation first before asking: [How much research is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I just start with the matter, I finished first basic course and this site was recommended to me as the place where I can ask questions and get answers. I am aware that I should look before I ask and I did that. And apparently I haven't found my answer. Well, I will look further.

Comment: You are correct to come here - but we just have a lot of people essentially asking "I don't know how to do this can you program it for me?" making it seem like you are working for them to write code. This community is more for debugging each other's code. Not for teaching something you can look in the documentation for or work through some tutorials. Just do a HTML&CSS tutorial. Chances are high it will teach how to create CSS on two pages eventually.

Comment: I will. Regards